# How to send XML-RPC request with HTTPS?

Tags: java, https, xml-rpc

I am new to XML-RPC and may be my question is silly but I can't find any information to help me for that...

So here it is : I am using this java code to send a XML file through a XML-RPC request using HTTP.

```
public static void sendXML(String file, String host, String port, String url) throws IOException{
    Socket socket = new Socket(host, Integer.parseInt(port));
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

StringBuffer header = new StringBuffer();
header.append("POST "+url+" HTTP/1.0\n");
header.append("Content-Type: text/xml\n");
header.append("Content-Length: "+(new File(file).length()+2)+"\n");
header.append("\n");

byte[] buffer = header.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
out.write(buffer);

InputStream src = new FileInputStream(file);       
buffer = new byte[1024];
int b = 0;
while((b = src.read(buffer)) >= 0){
    out.write(buffer, 0, b);
}   

buffer = "\n\n".getBytes("UTF-8");
out.write(buffer);

out.close();
src.close();
in.close();

out.flush();
socket.close();
}
```

In this code, the XML file is already created, containing the method called and all the parameters.
This solution works fine but I am asking to make it compatible for a HTTPS protocol.

Do I need to only change the line

```
header.append("POST "+url+" HTTP/1.0\n");
```

in

```
header.append("POST "+url+" HTTPS/1.0\n");
```

?

Or should I use the Apache library https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/client.html ?

Or may be is there any simpler solution in java language ?

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Your code is the equivalent of making breakfast by first raising chickens, then waiting for them to lay eggs. Smart people have created libraries so you don't need to reinvent the wheel in a slow, error-prone way. Use Apache's library, or see if there are others that may seem easier/better in your opinion, but do not open a low level socket if you're attempting to perform a high level action (XML-RPC).

Comment: Yes, I was in fact already starting changing my code using the Apache library. But is there any configuration to use it with a HTTPS server ?

Comment: Libraries also have documentation for that purpose. Besides, can't you google "apache xml-rpc https"?